# Navigation SlideMenu with even onChildClick ExpanListview hitch

Tags: javascript, java, c#, android

I have import sliding menu lib on android with expand `ListView`. But if `onChildClick` even on expandListView that it hitch. However it not crash but it for user feel uncomfortable.
Please You can help me
Sorry, because english not enough well.

This is my Code :

```
expanListView.setOnChildClickListener(new
ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

     @Override
     public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        switch (groupPosition) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                if(childPosition==1)
                {
                    MotoListFragment fragment1 = new MotoListFragment();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment1).addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    setViewToolBar.upDateListByke();
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleMenu();
                }
                else if (childPosition == 0){
                    MaintenanceFragment fragment = new MaintenanceFragment();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).toggleMenu();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```